# How can I break the loop if it hasn't finished in 10 seconds?

Tags: arduino-uno

Currently I am using [OneButton.h library](https://github.com/mathertel/OneButton) to code  my push button project.

When I press button1, it will loop for 10sec and print TRIG, and after that it will break the loop.

However, now I want to program it where when I pressed button1, it will jump to `void(singleclick)` function, but right now, during the 4th seconds (anytime before 10th sec) , I pressed other button, thus Arduino will break the 10sec loop and run other function.

Thus, I need help how to make sure Arduino actively read other button and when pressed, it will break the current loop/function to other related functions.

```
#include <OneButton.h>

OneButton button1(2, true);
OneButton button2(3, true);
OneButton button3(4, true);
OneButton button4(5, true);

int led1=12;
int led2=11;
int led3=10;
int led4=9;

int flag;

unsigned long mode;

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4,OUTPUT);

  button1.attachClick(singleclick1);
  button1.attachLongPressStop(longclick);

  button2.attachClick(singleclick2);
  button3.attachClick(singleclick3);
  button4.attachClick(singleclick4);

   digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led3,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led4,HIGH);
  
}

void loop()
{
  button1.tick();
  delay(20);

  button2.tick();
  delay(20);

  button3.tick();
  delay(20);

  button4.tick();
  delay(20);

  Serial.println("No button");

}

void singleclick1()
{
   mode=millis();

   flag=1;

   while(flag==1)
   {
     Serial.println("button1");
     digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
     digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
     digitalWrite(led4,LOW);
  
     if(millis()-mode>5000)
     {
      Serial.println("TRIG");
      flag=0;

      button2.tick();
      delay(20);
      
      button3.tick();
      delay(20);
      
      button4.tick();
      delay(20);
      
      return;
     }
   }
}

void singleclick2()
{
   Serial.println("button2");
   digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
   digitalWrite(led4,LOW);
}
```

Comment: You could run a timer that toggles a flag after 10 seconds. Then the loop would check that flag on each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rough, incomplete and untested code.

```
void singleclick1() { startTimer = true; }      // this only sets a flag

void singleclick2() { runTimer   = false;}      // this only clears a flag


void loop() {

   button1.tick();
   button2.tick();

   if startTimer {                 // this occurs once every click 1

      mode        = millis();
      runTimer    = true;
      startTimer  = false;         // run this block only once every click 1

      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW );
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW );
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW );
   }

   unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

   if (currentMillis - mode > 10000) {
      runTimer = false;                      // 10 second timer expired
   }

   if (runTimer) {

      Serial.println("TRIG");
         
   }
   else {
      // optional stuff to do
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!